# How secure are Launchpad repositories?

Tags: security, malware

I keep reading this: "if you only add packages from Launchpad you'll be safe."

Is there a peer review on every package or is it an assumption? Many packages on Playstore are infected, [for example this recently](https://androidcommunity.com/dresscode-malware-discovered-in-google-play-store-apps-20160901/).

Comment: The only safe repositories are the official ones. PPAs are *generally safe* (certainly safer than other options). That said your question is similar to "How safe is the water from natural springs? Can you see the problem? I hope so.